# how to hide url's in codeigniter when i am watching by using right click and inspect element?

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to hide url's in codeigniter when i am watching by using right click and inspect element ?

any one can u please help me ?

hiding url's when pressing cntrl+U and (view source)

or hiding url's in view source.

thanks

Comment: I think you can not do this. Why do you want to do this? Since, the data is transfered to the client browser, there are several technics to get the url from the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If the browser doesn't know what the URL is, it can't access it, so you have to tell the browser what is is.

The browser belongs to the user. It will tell the user whatever they want to know.